# Strange ggplot colour palette in reference key

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to plot density of new migrant gp registrations onto a local authority area map; My plot has worked to a reasonable extent except that I have no idea what has happened with the colour palette. I suspect it has become confused by the presence of decimals in the fill value. If you click on the picture you will probably note that the colour key is almost circular from beginning to end.

Does anybody know what might have happened here, how to avoid this in future and to resolve on this occasion with a better key?

[Result of current GGplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bT3lc.png)

```
install.packages("rgdal")
library(rgdal)
install.packages("maptools")
library(maptools)
install.packages("rgeos")
library(rgeos)
myshape2 <- readShapeSpatial("infuse_dist_lyr_2011.shp")
plot(myshape)
plot(myshape2)
install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)
str(myshape2)
myshape2frame <- fortify(myshape2, region="name")
install.packages("gpclib", type = "source")

pathRtools <- paste(c("c:\\Rtools\\bin",
                  "c:\\Rtools\\MinGW_64\\bin",
                  "c:\\MiKTeX\\miktex\\bin",
                  "c:\\R\\bin\\i386",
                  "c:\\windows",
                  "c:\\windows\\system32"), collapse=";")
Sys.setenv(PATH=paste(pathRtools,Sys.getenv("PATH"),sep=";"))
install.packages("gpclib", type = "source")
library(gpclib)
gpclibPermit()
gpclibPermitStatus()
# simplify the polgons a tad (tweak 0.00001 to your liking)
myshapebuffer <- gBuffer(myshape2, byid=TRUE, width=0)
View(myshapebuffer) # deal with bad polygons
plot(myshapebuffer)
myshape2frame <- fortify(myshapebuffer, region="name")
View(myshape2frame)
mig16 <- read.csv("migration.csv")
library(plyr)
intmig <- ggplot() + geom_map(data = mig16, aes(map_id = Area, fill = Mig), 
                map = myshape2frame) + expand_limits(x = myshape2frame$long,    y = myshape2frame$lat))
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant test this exactly, but I think the opposite (of the decimal issue), that the fill values are being treated as factors instead of as the real numeric values. Try changing `fill = Mig` to `fill = as.numeric(as.character(Mig))`.

(Remember that factors have to be converted to character, before being converted to the desired numeric value).

Comment: thank you, this seems to have been an issue because after trying your suggestion colours have returned normally and the scale is now 40 - 80 - 120 - 160 which is much more sensible.   This said I will need to change the scale somehow to exaggerate the regional differences. What seems to have happened is that high values in some places e.g london have dragged up the scale and made the significant differences elsewhere vanish - its all the same shade of blue!

Comment: Good to hear! Scaling the values will be important. have a look at the `scales` package that `ggplot2` imports for some quick help